# Browse a file from one page and display its contents into another page

Tags: php, html

The task is to browse a file from an HTML file named as `upload.html`

```
<html>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="my-file" size="50" maxlength="25"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"></form></body>
```

And display the matching content of a browsed file into another page through `upload.php`. This file contains:

```
<?php
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['my-file']['error']==0) {
     echo "The file was uploaded successfully but has not been saved.<br>";
     echo "The file is temporarily stored: " . $_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name'] . "<br>";
     echo "The file name was: " . $_FILES['my-file']['name'] . "<br>";
     echo "The file type is: " . $_FILES['my-file']['type'] . "<br>";
   } else {
     echo "(Error Code:" . $_FILES['my-file']['error'] . ")";
}


$file = $_FILES['my-file'];
$out = file_get_contents($file);
$delimiter = '#';
$startTag0= '#';
$endTag0='freq';
$regex0 = $delimiter . preg_quote($startTag0, $delimiter) 
                . '(.*?)' 
                . preg_quote($endTag0, $delimiter) 
                . $delimiter 
                . 's';
preg_match($regex0,$out,$matches);
$match0 = $matches[0]."<br>";
echo "<pre>".$match0."</pre>";
```

However it does not produce an output based on file ...

Comment: You need to use the $_FILES superglobal array in order to get the file, not $_POST. Read about fileuploads in PHP here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php ... Also this `file_get_contents('$file');` will try to open a file named `$file` which you probably don't want. You probably want to omit the quotes.

Comment: @EJTH Thanks for your response... I change $file = $_FILES['upload'] . Is there is any thing more to add to get expected output. And it will browsing a file in html page and button named as 'upload'. This' upload' name is passed in sample_copy.php file

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `include ('browse.html');`

Comment: Thanks for your response... Even though include('browse.html') is given, it does not display content of the file that I browse in html page.

Comment: is there any warning or error? you should check path to file too. Are both files in same folder?

Comment: It doesnt showing any warning or error message. Both browse.html and sample_copy.php are in same folder. It gives a blank screen.

Comment: it shows error ...............                                                                           Warning: file_get_contents($file): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/molecule/sample_copy.php               It doesnot taking the file path that I browsed in html page

Comment: file not found, check path and file name one more time, maybe some mistake ;)

Comment: I edit the code as $file= $_FILES['upload'] but it doesnot display file content that I browsed in html file.